# Перевод числа с плавающей точкой в бинарное

Tags: c++

Написал функцию, которая, как мне хочется, должна переводить дробное число в двоичное, но она не работает.
Целая часть числа преобразуется в двоичное с помощью встроенной функции `itoa(int, char array, 2);` , для остатка после точки я написал свою функцию `dec_bin`, в которой число умножается на 2, потом первый символ запоминается, меняется на 0 и так далее...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
string dec_bin(string dec, int steps) {
    double decimal = stof(dec); // 0.987
    string str_decimal = "";
    string decimal_bin = "";

    for(int i = 0; i < steps; i++) {
        decimal *= 2; //1.974
        str_decimal = to_string(decimal);
        decimal_bin += str_decimal[0];                  // "1", "11", "111" ...
        str_decimal = str_decimal.replace(0, 1, "0"); //  "0.974"
        decimal = stof(str_decimal);                    // 0.974

    }
    return decimal_bin;


}
string float_to_bin(string input, int steps) {
    string result, whole;
    short sign = 0; // + by default
    char whole_bin[20];

    if(input.find('-') != -1) // in "-1.974"
        sign = 1; // for -1.974
    int point_pos = input.find('.');

    if(point_pos != -1) {
        whole = input.substr(0, point_pos);
        string dec = "0" + input.substr(point_pos, input.size() - point_pos);  //"0.987"
    }
    else {
        whole = input;
    }


    int int_whole = stoi(whole);
    itoa(int_whole, whole_bin, 2); //""

    if(point_pos != -1) {
        string dec_bin;
    }






    if(point_pos != -1) {
        string whole_bin_res(20, whole_bin); // convert char to string
        result =whole_bin_res + "." + dec_bin(to_string(dec), steps);
    }
    else 
        result = whole_bin;


    return  sign, result;
}





int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    cout << "Enter a decimal number: ";
    string input = "12.987";

    cout << float_to_bin(input, 3);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Не вижу у вас проверку бита. Я бы умножал на два, и проверял первый бит, т.е. типа `str_decimal = str_decimal + ((  ((int)(floor(decimal ))) & 1 ) ? '0' : '1' )` отбросить дробную часть, и проверить бит 1.

Comment: Алгоритм очень запутанный - лень распутывать. Выберите один случай, и упростите, тут максимум... два цикла и пару проверок должно остаться.

Comment: @nick_n_a она преобразует строку в число с плавающей точкой. Я же хочу преобразовать десятичное дробное число (12.987) в двоичное и вернуть строку("1100.111"). Даже если я преобразую свой ввод в дробное число(через atof()), то я не знаю функции, которая бы могла перевести float в binary.

Comment: @nick_n_a проверка бита присутствует, хотя, возможно, и на примитивном уровне. Она в цикле с  11 строки

Comment: `.111` - это `0.875`,  а не `0.987` 7/8 != 987/1000

Comment: float  в binary - легко. `union {  float myFloat; unsigned char myBinary[sizeof(float)] ; }`; ну... как-то так. Остаётся среди двочного представления отделить мантису от порядка (читать теорию)

Comment: Смотрите, ряд идет 0.5, 0.25, 0.125, 0.0625  ... и так далее делением на два, .111 => 0.5+ 0.25 + 0.125 = 0.875 Поэтому при малых размерах мантисы очень легко теряются числа.

Comment: я бы перебирал количество разрядов после точки в двоичном представлении, и пытался подобрать `x` из `x/2^n` == `y/10^m`, где `n` - количество разрядов после точки в бинарном представлении, `m` - количество разрядов после точки в десятичном представлении, а `y` - значение числа после точки в десятично представлении (как в примере x/2^n == 987/10^3). Перебирал бы я `n`. Вам же строка на выходе нужна, длина не ограничена (можно погрешность ввести какую-нибудь, чтобы останавливаться при хорошем приближении)

Comment: Подбор - не даст хороший результат, какая у вас задача? Получить двоичное представление? Допустим - сразу вопрос - до какой точности? Или до какой разрядности мантисы?

Comment: @vegorov я знаю, как это делается. Внизу я вызывал свою функцию `float_to_bin(input, 3);` и написал бы я не 3, а 6 - то и число было бы точнее

Comment: @february а я вот понятия не имею как это правильно делается. nick_n_a полагаю знает

Comment: Пока не оговорена точность вычислений, этой задачей можно пригрузить даже програмиста с опытом. Главная загвоздка задачи - точность. Нельзя сделать что б `a10 = b2` это равенство на практике не будет сохранятся. всегда будет `a10 = b2 +/- epsilon` Если точность до сотых, то епсилон нужно 1/1000 задать.

Comment: @nick_n_a Задача следующая: написать программу, которая бы переводила  десятичные числа в Разрядно-Логарифмическое Представление(далее РЛП) и назад. Например, десятичное число 12.25 в РЛП это [0 6 3 2 1 -2]. Если загнать в программу 0 6 3 2 1 -2 , то выводить она должна 12.25.

Comment: РЛП - я не знаком. В биты могу перевести, теоретически. На практике - надо попробовать несколько вариантов, что б учесть потерю точности. О вот вариант готовый http://prog-cpp.ru/notation/

Comment: @nick_n_a спасибо, это должно существенно упростить задачу

Comment: Второй вариант - подобрать макс число кратное двойке, делить его всёвремя на 2, и вычитать. Если вычитание даёт минус - то не вычитаем и пишем ноль. Если вычитается - вычитаем и пишем 1. При переходе ведущего за 1, добавляем точку.

Comment: При вычислений с double и с float нужно понимать что точность результата зависит от разрядности мантисы.  msdn float - 6-9 цифр - максимум 9. double 15-17 - 10-тичных цифр. Если делать не используя стандартную мантису - задача усложняется в разы.